# Dynamic FieldName for GridViewDataTextColumn (<%# Eval(...)%>)

Tags: c#, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an in-memory DataSet bound to an ASPxGridView where the column names are determined by a variable. Now I would prefer to assign the FieldName of the columns in the markup with the value of the corresponding variable, but `<%#Eval(...)%>` throws the following error.

```
Parser Error Message: Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewDataTextColumn does not have a DataBinding event.
```

Is it possible to assign the FieldName-Attribute of a GridViewDataTextColumn with a variable in the markup?

From

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Product" FieldName="product_name">
```

To

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Product" FieldName="<%# Eval("ProductFieldName") %>">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, in general. The GridViewDataTextColumn is a hierarchycal (non Data-Bound) element and it is not contained into a Data-Bound container.

According to the exception's message, I believe this is a common situation for such an ASP.NET controls:

[DataBinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event.](http://www.google.com/search?q=Databinding+expressions+are+only+supported+on+objects+that+have+a+DataBinding+event.&oq=Databinding+expressions+are+only+supported+on+objects+that+have+a+DataBinding+event)

I believe it is possible to specify the required properties and assign column FieldName at runtime as it is illustrated [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2967.aspx).

Comment: Thanks :) I already knew the way doing it at runtime. I thought I missed something so it could be done the other way directly in the markup.